# How to get separate BPM readings from two pulse sensors using one Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

Here is the code I used to get BPM from pulse sensor.

```cpp
#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true    // Set-up low-level interrupts for most 
acurate BPM math.
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>     // Includes the PulseSensorPlayground 
Library.
```

//  Variables

```
const int PULSE_SENSOR_COUNT = 2;
const int PulseWire = A0;
const int PulseWire2 = A1;
const int LED13 = 13;
int Threshold = 550;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire, 0);
  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire2, 1);
  pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(LED13);
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);
  if (pulseSensor.begin()) {
  }

  void loop() {
    int myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();  // Calls function on our pulseSensor object that returns BPM as an "int".

    if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) {            // Constantly test to see if "a beat happened".
      //Serial.println("♥  A HeartBeat Happened ! "); // If test is "true", print a message "a heartbeat happened".
      Serial.print("BPM1: ");                        // Print phrase "BPM: "
      Serial.println(myBPM);                        // Print the value inside of myBPM.
    }
    delay(20);                    // considered best practice in a simple sketch.
  }
```

I wish to separate display the BPM that get from A0 wire and A1 wire. Serial could print something like this: `BPM1(A0):75, BPM2(A1):80`.
I don't know how to do that, can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Your sketch does not compile. What libraries are you using?

Comment: I am using PulseSensorPlayground Library. And I just added the library code on top

Comment: Could you please make it clearer what you are trying to achieve. I suggest you reword your last paragraph. Perhaps a picture would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS **true**" to "#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS **false**".

> If, instead, your Sketch does not use interrupts to read PulseSensor data, your Sketch must instead contain the following two lines, in order:
>
> #define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS false
>
> #include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>

Source: https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensorPlayground/blob/master/src/PulseSensorPlayground.h

Comment: thank you, but I am still struggling on how to print different BPM

Comment: The next line of code you are missing is on line number 146: https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensorPlayground/blob/master/src/PulseSensorPlayground.h. Please read all the comments in PulseSensorPlayground.h. Let's make sure we are looking identical libraries.

Comment: Have a look at this sketch: https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensorPlayground/blob/master/examples/TwoPulseSensors_On_OneArduino/TwoPulseSensors_On_OneArduino.ino

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem now. And thanks for being patient with me, I am really new to Arduino.